# Set memory limit for debugging in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In an application I'm working on, under certain conditions the memory usage will shoot through the roof, effectively locking up my computer. I don't think it's a memory leak, and there are no errors, it just needs too much memory. The memory usage jumps to 99% in Task Manager and Windows stops working, forcing me to reboot.

Is it possible to set a maximum amount of memory VS can use while debugging? I'm not looking for a way to make it run out of memory faster, I just want to keep some memory free so Windows can keep working.

- Visual Studio 2010
- Windows 7 64b
- 8GB RAM
- C# .NET

---

Edit:
I'm not asking how to fix a memory leak. I'm trying to limit the memory used by the VS debugger. For example, my PC has 8GB RAM, but my application has to run on a PC with 2GB RAM. So I want to configure VS to only use 2GB. If the application tries to allocate 2.0001GB I want VS to tell it there is no more memory (probably causing a crash).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817660.aspx

Comment: A very informative article, but sadly it does not answer my question.

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/sdorman/archive/2008/08/28/visual-studio-optimizations.aspx

Comment: Technically, it is possible to provide a memory allocator to the [CLR Hosting Interfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164336.aspx). I don't know, if those are being used by the debugger, or (if they are), whether they can be configured. The edit, however, reveals a common misconception. A machine with 2GB RAM can very well run programs that use more then 2GB (see [About Memory Management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366525.aspx)). Unless I'm misunderstanding what you were saying.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly the answer you were looking for, but it might help others, so I'm posting:
I would try the following:
1) Download [Oracle Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/VirtualBox)
2) Download [Disk2VHD.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx)from Microsoft Sysinternals
3) Clone your system using Disk2VHD
4) Configure a VM with the memory restrictions you want.

In this way you can restrict the RAM and CPUs used by your task, and possibly recover easier from the case you describe.